# Symbolic Math in MATLAB, solving simple integration

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a problem with solving a simple integration through MATLAB. I want to solve this symbolic and don't have any problems doing this through other programs.

Well I have this equation:

syms k x

fX(x) = k * e^(-3*x) for 2 <= x <= 6

which I want to integrate from the interval 2 to 6. Then I would solve the equation, so that fX(x) = 1, and solve the equation for k. I type:

S = solve('int(k*exp(-3*x),x,2,6) = 1',k);

And I get following error:
Error, (in int) wrong number (or type) of arguments: invalid options or option values passed to indefinite
integration. Unknown options: {2, 6}

Why can't the int-function not take my limits?

Comment: Did you already assign a value to x?

Comment: no... I have following:

syms k x
S = solve('int(k*exp(-3*x),x,2,6) = 1',k);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`solve(int(k*exp(-3*x),x,2,6) - 1,k)` should work :)

Notice:

1. don't use = 1 but -1 (that means f(x) - 1 = 0)
2. don't use ''

The result for me is:

```
-(3*exp(6))/(1/exp(12) - 1)
```

I also tried to solve it by hand and got the same result.

Comment: Thanks! ... That did the trick, but why can't that solve-command not handle equations other then (=0)?

Comment: @Soren: It can. You should not use string input, and you should use the `==` equality sign. (And if you do use string input, that has to be in MuPAD syntax, `'int(k*exp(-3*x),x=2..6) == 1'`. But don't do that.)